# JQuery/ Javascript not executing in simple HTML form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a webpage and I have this form that will execute a script once the submit button is pressed. I plan to add AJAX in to push data to a PHP script, but for now I can't even get the javascript code block to run. Am i doing something wrong? In addition, I do have the includes for jQuery.

Below are snippets of my code.

```
  <!--Scripts -->
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!--Legacy jQuery support for quicksand plugin-->
  <script src="js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

            <div class="col-md-6">
              <form id="contact-form" role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="sr-only" for="contact-name">Name</label>
                  <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="contact-name" placeholder="Name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="sr-only" for="contact-email">Email</label>
                  <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="contact-email" placeholder="Email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="sr-only" for="contact-message">Message</label>
                  <textarea rows="12" name="message" class="form-control" id="contact-message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Send Message">
              </form>

                <!-- Function To Submit Contact Us Form-->
                <script type="text/javascript">
                $("#contact-form").submit(function(event) {
                    alert("Dammit");
                });
                </script>
            </div>
```

When clicking submit the Web Browser URL shows the fields and content from the form, however the alert is not being executed. I appreciate any assistance in advanced.

Comment: Typo. `$("contact-form")` should be `$("#contact-form")`.

Comment: It's only a typo if you assume that OP knows what `#` does, which you can't assume from the question. No need to close the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $("#contact-form").submit(function(event) {
      alert("Dammit");
  });
```

You need the # character when querying for an element by ID. Your code is currently looking for a tag named `contact-form`

Comment: You should vote to close questions with typos, not try to farm rep from them.

Comment: @j08691 It's not your typical typo, since it's still a valid selector and the OP may not know what the `#` means.

Comment: @JuanMendes - Oh it's quite typical. And how is it valid since there's no `<contact form>` element?

Comment: @j08691 You can create custom elements and it would work, that's how angular works http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/7hYUr/

Comment: Thanks @JuanMendes for the useful edit, I'm new to answering questions but I'll try to be more insightful in future answers.

Comment: I modified it to reflect #contact-form, but it still doesn't seem to execute anything. I have two forms in this html page as well, so i just didnt want to simply write just "form"

Comment: You could, alternatively, set an onclick event on your submit button which would call a JS function.

Comment: `$("#YourSubmitBTN").click(function(event) {
        alert("Dammit");
     });`